# Unable to load data using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to AngularJS and trying to understand it. 
Currently, I am not able to load the data received from PHP using ng-repeat. However, I am able to trace the data in a controller function.
Here is data I am getting from server (PHP)

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["ProjectID"]=>
    string(4) "1830"
    ["ProjectName"]=>
    string(4) "ABCD"
    ["ProjectCode"]=>
    string(8) "abc11111"
    ["Task"]=>
    string(6) "Update"
    ["ProjectStatus"]=>
    string(8) "Complete"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["ProjectID"]=>
    string(4) "1831"
    ["ProjectName"]=>
    string(4) "EFGH"
    ["ProjectCode"]=>
    string(8) "abc22222"
    ["Task"]=>
    string(6) "New"
    ["ProjectStatus"]=>
    string(8) "Inprogress"
  }
}
```

AngularJS Code:

```
$scope.url = "GetProjects.php?stDate="+ startDate + "&edDate=" + endDate;
                $http({method: $scope.method, url: $scope.url, cache: $templateCache})
                    .success(function(data, status) 
                    {
                        $scope.status = status;
                        $scope.projects = (data);
                        for (var i=0;i<$scope.projects.length; i++)
                        {
                            alert ($scope.projects[i].ProjectName);
                        }
                    })
```

HTML Code:

```
<div ng-app="seReportApp">
    <div ng-controller="GetProjectsController">
        <table border="1">
            <tr> 
                <td>ProjectName</td>
                <td>ProjectCode</td>
                <td>project.Task</td>
                <td>project.ProjectStatus</td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="project in $scope.projects"> 
                <td>{{ project.ProjectName }}</td>
                <td>{{ project.ProjectCode }}</td>
                <td>{{ project.Task }}</td>
                <td>{{ project.ProjectStatus }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you don't need to referece $scope inside the ng-repeat expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a ng-repeat in order to make it work. Copy the following lines in your html, it will give you a good example of a ng-repeat usage. You should see your projects in a table.

```
<table class="table">
  <tr ng-repeat="project in projects">
    <td>{{ project.ProjectName }}</td>
    <td>{{ project.ProjectCode }}</td>
    <td>{{ project.Task }}</td>
    <td>{{ project.ProjectStatus }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I hope it helped you.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was very simple solution.